# Error while working on DXA 1.4 and WEB 8

Tags: dxa, web8

I am getting below error while running the application

> An exception of type 'System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException' occurred in Sdl.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Unauthorized Request -- Please check your configuration settings to make sure your authentication details are correct.

Not sure which which authentication details i need to pass i am following the the [doc link](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20DXA-v4&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-EDB49D8A-DCC3-45E7-B809-6A8B377C4FEA&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-EDB49D8A-DCC3-45E7-B809-6A8B377C4FEA.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-EDB49D8A-DCC3-45E7-B809-6A8B377C4FEA)

Comment: Can you fix the documentation link, it currently points to the error message rather than an actual url?

Comment: What is in the DXA log file (C:\Temp\logs\Site.log by default)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please update the `web.config` file and toggle value of `oauth-enabled` to `true`.

```
<add key="oauth-enabled" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

**In Web.config:**

```
   <!-- CIL caching can be enabled on Staging; CIL 8.1.1+ will bypass the cache for XPM Session Preview.  The service-caching-expiration setting is in seconds. -->
<add key="service-caching" value="true" />
<add key="service-caching-expiration" value="60" />
<add key="oauth-enabled" value="true" />
<add key="oauth-client-id" value="cduser" />
<add key="oauth-client-secret" value="CDUserP@ssw0rd" />
```

1. Set oauth-enabled" value="true"
2. Set the same Token as in cd-client and cwd-client conf for "ClientSecret" in
   web config for key="oauth-client-secret" value="CDUserP@ssw0rd"