# "Unauthorized Request" Error - while running the DXA application 1.7 and Web 8

Tags: dxa, web8, content-delivery, dxa-1.7, dxa-net

I am getting below error while running the DXA application:

> Unauthorized Request -- Please check your configuration settings to make sure your authentication details are correct.

I have gone through several questions ([one of sample question](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14397/error-while-working-on-dxa-1-4-and-web-8)) having same issue and cross checked the config details provided in those solutions. But still I am getting this error. Below is my settings in `web.config`:

```
<add key="discovery-serviceuri"value="http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc"/>    
<add key="cid-service-proxy-pattern" value="/cid*" />
<add key="cid-localhost" value="localhost" />
<add key="log-level" value="INFO" />
<add key="log-rolling" value="true" />
<add key="log-max-log-size" value="50000" />
<add key="log-output" value="C:\temp\logs\cd_client_Test.log" />
<add key="oauth-enabled" value="true" />
<add key="oauth-client-id" value="cduser" />
```

**Stack Trace:**

> [AuthenticationException: Unauthorized Request -- Please check your
>   configuration settings to make sure your authentication details are
>   correct.]    Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.PerformRetry(Func`1 block,
>   Int32 retryCount) +113    Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.Retry(Func`1
>   block, Int32 retryCount, Boolean locking) +205
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.Execute(ODataV4ClientFunction
>   function) +178
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.ContentService.ContentServiceClient.Execute(ODataV4ClientFunction
>   function) +60
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Dynamic.DynamicMappingsRetrieverImpl.GetPublicationMapping(String
>   url) +178
>   Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.DynamicMappingsRetriever.GetPublicationMapping(String
>   url) +64
>   Sdl.Web.Tridion.CdApiLocalizationResolver.ResolveLocalization(Uri url)
>   in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App
>   .NET\Sdl.Web.Tridion\CdApiLocalizationResolver.cs:64
>   Sdl.Web.Mvc.Configuration.WebRequestContext.GetCurrentLocalization()
>   in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App
>   .NET\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Configuration\WebRequestContext.cs:214
>   Sdl.Web.Mvc.Configuration.WebRequestContext.get_Localization() in
>   C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App
>   .NET\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Configuration\WebRequestContext.cs:25
>   Sdl.Web.Mvc.Statics.StaticContentModule.BeginRequest(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) in C:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App
>   .NET\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Statics\StaticContentModule.cs:81
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +141    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +71

Kindly point me if I am missing something?
**Update**
Got the below Trace from the log file:

> 2018-04-12 15:20:19 DEBUG [Sdl.Web.Delivery.ADF.HttpModule..cctor] -
>   Ambient Data context initialization. 2018-04-12 15:20:21 DEBUG
>   [Sdl.Web.Delivery.DiscoveryService.DiscoveryServiceProvider..ctor] -
>   Attempting to construct discovery-service provider. 
>   
> 2018-04-12
>   15:20:21 TRACE
>   [Sdl.Web.Delivery.DiscoveryService.DiscoveryServiceClient..ctor]
>         Registering OData V2 Service: http://server:port/discovery.svc/
>   2018-04-12 15:20:21 TRACE
>   [Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.FireSendingRequest2]
>         OData V4 Service Request:
>   http://server:port/discovery.svc/TokenServiceCapabilities?$top=1 (GET)
>         OData-Version:4.0       OData-MaxVersion:4.0
>         Accept:application/json;odata.metadata=minimal
>         Accept-Charset:UTF-8        User-Agent:Microsoft ADO.NET Data Services
>   2018-04-12 15:20:23 DEBUG
>   [Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.OAuthTokenProvider..ctor] - Using
>   token-service: http://serverIP:port/token.svc 2018-04-12 15:20:23
>   DEBUG
>   [Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.OAuthTokenProvider.CreateOrRefreshToken] -
>   Attempting to get token from token-service. 2018-04-12 15:20:24 TRACE
>   [Sdl.Web.Delivery.OAuthClient.AuthenticationClient.ProcessRequest]
>         Token service response: Proxy Authorization
>   Required
>
> ## Proxy Authorization Required
>
> ---
>
> **Description: Authorization is required
>   for access to this proxy**
>
> ---
>
> 2018-04-12
>   15:20:36 ERROR
>   [Sdl.Web.Delivery.ContentService.ContentServiceProvider..ctor]
>         Problem authenticating with service. Please make sure your
>   authentication settings are correct and you have enabled
>   authentication.

Comment: Sounds like a mismatch in your oauth security settings, note that in the `web.config` you are showing you exposed the default credentials (I would suggest never to expose credentials and passwords in a public question like this, not even the default one), is that the same ones that you have on the Content Delivery services?

Comment: 1. Is that content service/discovery service enabled OAuth authentication? 
2. Is it registered correctly with discovery correctly with correct OAuth credentials?
3. double check your credentials on this file `discovery\config\cd_ambient_conf.xml`?

Comment: @BartKoopman, i removed the credentials from question, thanks for pointing it out. Yes that is the same as i have in Content Delivery.

Comment: @Velmurugan, I checked the credentials on the cd_ambient_config.xml and found its correct.Checked Discovery service and it's enabled.

Comment: Using postman to check the athentication with discovery service from webapp server

Comment: @SDLBeginner Could be an issue with symbol hyphen '-' in the web.config for the keys oauth‐client‐id and oauth‐client‐secret, double check this could be the same issue as reported here, https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/19040/cil-token-service-unauthorized-request

Comment: @Velmurugan, i tried replacing hyphen sign "-" too, but am getting the same above error. When i try to hit the discovery-service-uri, it's returning me `{"error":"invalid_grant"}`.