# DD4T webapp using discovery service gets 'invalid_grant'

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dd4t-2, discovery-service

There are a lot of articles about the 'invalid_grant' error but I didn't find an answer on my situation.

At first, with Postman I am able to get an access token from /token.svc and use it successfully on the discovery service (with the cduser account).

When I run the .NET webapplication (using the DD4T.Providers.DxaModelService package)I get the following error:

```
[DataServiceClientException: {"error":"invalid_grant"}]
   Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.ExecuteQuery() +478
   Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute(DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents) +254

[DataServiceQueryException: An error occurred while processing this request.]
   Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute(DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents) +628
   Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.GetEnumerator() +22
   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +220
   Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQueryProvider.ReturnSingleton(Expression expression) +530
   Sdl.Web.ModelService.ModelServiceClient.GetModelServiceUri(String uri) +146
   Sdl.Web.ModelService.ModelServiceClient..ctor() +126
   DD4T.Providers.DxaModelService.BaseProvider..ctor(IProvidersCommonServices providersCommonServices) +137
   lambda_method(Closure , Object[] ) +104
   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate() +270

[DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts.Providers.IProvidersCommonServices)' on type 'TridionPageProvider'. ---> An error occurred while processing this request. (See inner exception for details.)]
   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate() +814
   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +269
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) +110

[DependencyResolutionException: An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = TridionPageProvider (ReflectionActivator), Services = [DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts.Providers.IPageProvider], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts.Providers.IProvidersCommonServices)' on type 'TridionPageProvider'. ---> An error occurred while processing this request. (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.)]
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) +433
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() +180
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +171
   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate() +119
   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +269
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) +110

[DependencyResolutionException: An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = PageFactory (ReflectionActivator), Services = [DD4T.ContentModel.Factories.IPageFactory], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = TridionPageProvider (ReflectionActivator), Services = [DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts.Providers.IPageProvider], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts.Providers.IProvidersCommonServices)' on type 'TridionPageProvider'. ---> An error occurred while processing this request. (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.)]
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) +433
   Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id, Func`1 creator) +155
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() +166
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +171
   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate() +119
   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +269
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) +110

[DependencyResolutionException: An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = PageController (ReflectionActivator), Services = [MijnPostNL.Controllers.PageController], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = PageFactory (ReflectionActivator), Services = [DD4T.ContentModel.Factories.IPageFactory], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = TridionPageProvider (ReflectionActivator), Services = [DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts.Providers.IPageProvider], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts.Providers.IProvidersCommonServices)' on type 'TridionPageProvider'. ---> An error occurred while processing this request. (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.)]
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) +433
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() +180
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +171
   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +108
   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance) +122
   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptionalService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters) +70
   Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver.GetService(Type serviceType) +95
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +61

[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'MijnPostNL.Controllers.PageController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +242
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +103
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +263
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +77
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +1122
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +213
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +131
```

My web.config has the following configuration:

```
<!-- Configuration of the Discovery Service -->
<add key="discovery-service-uri" value="http://<domain>/discovery.svc" />
<add key="oauth-enabled" value="true" />
<add key="oauth-client-id" value="cduser" />
<add key="oauth-client-secret" value="CDUserP@ssw0rd" />
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this error?

Update: I had a look at Fiddler and there is no token being requested:

[image]

Comment: The config looks OK and this should work, however I must ask. Did you copy the keys from a pdf maybe? If yes, then try typing them in by hand. See https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/19040/cil-token-service-unauthorized-request

Comment: Hi @AtilaSos, I retyped the appSettings (keys and values) but I still get the same error.

Comment: from the stack trace above: InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'MijnPostNL.Controllers.PageController'. `Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Fiddler I found out that the TokenService was registered on the localhost domain. That's why the webapplication (which was running on my local machine) couldn't access the TokenService on the development server.

See screenshot below:

[image]

I configured the TokenService with a domainname and now it works.